# broadcasting across tensors in `pytorch`

Tags: arrays, gpu, pytorch

I am using pytorch as an array processing language (not for the traditional deep learning purposes), and I am wondering what the canonical way is to do "batching" parallelism.

For example, suppose I want to compute svds of two dimensional layers of a 3-d tensor (using `torch.svd()`, say), and I want to return a tuple of stacked `u`s, stacked `s`, stacked `v`.

Presumably, through the magic of SIMD parallelism, this should be doable in roughly the same time as a single layer svd (on gpu), but how to program it?

Comment: Please include a full [mcve] to help with the question. Specifically, you can replace questionable parts with pseudocode or similar to make it more understandable.

Comment: Not sure I understand this question. Pytorch already supports SVD on batched data, what exactly are you hoping to do that differs from the existing implementation?

Comment: @jodag I had implemented a partial SVD (to get the K top singular values/vectors). Going through my code, all the torch functions are batchable (qr, svd, mm, transpose), so all good. if you know of a canonical torch function to do this, I am all ears/eyes.

Comment: Unfortunately truncated SVD isn't currently supported (though there is an [open feature request](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8049) which appears to implemented and awaiting pull request). Also two related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58026949) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133809) which you may find useful.

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch is a high level software library with lots of python wrappers for highly optimized compiled code. A function or operator either supports batch data or not. 
There is no other way around it than writing your own C/C++/CUDA code and invoke it with python.

Luckily, most functions support batch processing (including `torch.svd()` as pointed out by [jodag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2790047/jodag)) and it can be assumed that the developers (or the compiler) paid attention to data parallelism in the implementation. I recommend you to stack your tensors wherever you can. It usually leads to significant speedups.

Note that the batch dimension is always the first dimension of a tensor. PyTorch supports broadcasting for common operators like `+, -, *, /` as documented [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html). Because of possible ambiguities you are sometimes required to reshape your data accordingly to make clear what you want. For example if you want to add a batch of scalars to a batch of vectors you need to do something like:

```
a = torch.zeros(2, 2)
b = torch.arange(2)
a + b.view(2, 1) # or b.reshape(2, 1)
# tensor([[0., 0.],
          [1., 1.]])
```